# Problem compiling QT4 in Beyond Linux From Scratch 7.8

Tags: compiling, qt, lfs, qt4

I'm using a VirtualBox machine (32 bit) to build BLFS to comply with the Linux Standard Base (all the packages mentioned in the book (http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.8/), with *required* and *recommended*, but trying to avoid *optional* packages). As the title says, I can't get BLFS 7.8 to completely build Qt 4.8.7.

According to the BLFS 7.8 book, it's supposed to build the following:

Installed Programs:
assistant, designer, lconvert, linguist, lrelease, lupdate, moc, pixeltool, qcollectiongenerator, qdbuscpp2xml, qdbus, qdbusviewer, qdbusxml2cpp, qdoc3, qhelpconverter, qhelpgenerator, qmake, qmlplugindump, qmlviewer, qt3to4, qtconfig, qttracereplay, rcc, uic3, uic, xmlpatterns, and xmlpatternsvalidator

Installed Libraries:
libQtUiTools.a, libQt3Support.so, libQtCLucene.so, libQtCore.so, libQtDBus.so, libQtDeclarative.so, libQtDesignerComponents.so, libQtDesigner.so, libQtGui.so, libQtHelp.so, libQtMultimedia.so, libQtNetwork.so, libQtOpenGL.so, libQtScript.so, libQtScriptTools.so, libQtSql.so, libQtSvg.so, libQtTest.so, libQtWebKit.so, libQtXmlPatterns.so, and libQtXml.so, and several plugins under /opt/qt4/imports and /opt/qt4/plugins

It builds all the libraries, but not all of the programs: qdbuscpp2xml, qdbus, qdbusviewer, qdbusxml2cpp, qmake, xmlpatterns, and xmlpatternsvalidator are not built.

Since most of the programs left out have dbus in their names, I checked systemctl and the result is the following:

```
UNIT    LOAD    ACTIVE  SUB
proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount   loaded  active  waiting
org.freedesktop.hostname1.busname   loaded  inactive    dead
org.freedesktop.locale1.busname loaded  inactive    dead
org.freedesktop.login1.busname  loaded  inactive    dead
org.freedesktop.machine1.busname    loaded  inactive    dead
org.freedesktop.network1.busname    loaded  inactive    dead
org.freedesktop.resolve1.busname    loaded  inactive    dead
org.freedesktop.systemd1.busname    loaded  inactive    dead
org.freedesktop.timedate1.busname   loaded  inactive    dead
dev-cdrom.device    loaded  active  plugged
dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dVBOX_CD\x2dROM_VB2\x2d01700376.device  loaded  active  plugged
dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dVBOX_HARDDISK_VB1b03ea62\x2ddbc63e3e.device    loaded  active  plugged
dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dVBOX_HARDDISK_VB1b03ea62\x2ddbc63e3e\x2dpart1.device   loaded  active  plugged
dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dVBOX_HARDDISK_VB661dfc8e\x2d76a9fb53.device    loaded  active  plugged
dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dVBOX_HARDDISK_VB661dfc8e\x2d76a9fb53\x2dpart1.device   loaded  active  plugged
dev-disk-by\x2duuid-adf6eeae\x2d5ab2\x2d42a3\x2d9e1d\x2d0fed7f32a451.device loaded  active  plugged
dev-disk-by\x2duuid-eb028a99\x2d93f4\x2d4b71\x2d98b4\x2daaf40d3d6c84.device loaded  active  plugged
dev-sda.device  loaded  active  plugged
dev-sda1.device loaded  active  plugged
dev-sdb.device  loaded  active  plugged
dev-sdb1.device loaded  active  plugged
dev-sr0.device  loaded  active  plugged
dev-ttyS0.device    loaded  active  plugged
dev-ttyS1.device    loaded  active  plugged
dev-ttyS2.device    loaded  active  plugged
dev-ttyS3.device    loaded  active  plugged
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.1-ata1-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:0-block-sda-sda1.device loaded active  plugged VBOX_HARDDISK 1
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.1-ata1-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:0-block-sda.device loaded  active  plugged
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.1-ata1-host0-target0:0:1-0:0:1:0-block-sdb-sdb1.device loaded active  plugged VBOX_HARDDISK 1
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.1-ata1-host0-target0:0:1-0:0:1:0-block-sdb.device loaded  active  plugged
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.1-ata2-host1-target1:0:0-1:0:0:0-block-sr0.device loaded  active  plugged
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS0.device    loaded  active  plugged
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS1.device    loaded  active  plugged
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS2.device    loaded  active  plugged
sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS3.device    loaded  active  plugged
sys-devices-virtual-net-sit0.device loaded  active  plugged
sys-subsystem-net-devices-sit0.device   loaded  active  plugged
-.mount loaded  active  mounted
dev-hugepages.mount loaded  active  mounted
dev-mqueue.mount    loaded  active  mounted
proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount   loaded  inactive    dead
sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount   loaded  inactive    dead
sys-kernel-config.mount loaded  inactive    dead
sys-kernel-debug.mount  loaded  active  mounted
tmp.mount   loaded  active  mounted
var-lib-machines.mount  loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-ask-password-console.path   loaded  active  waiting
systemd-ask-password-wall.path  loaded  active  waiting
alsa-restore.service    loaded  inactive    dead
alsa-state.service  loaded  inactive    dead
alsa-store.service  loaded  inactive    dead
auditd.service  not-found inactive  dead    auditd.service
dbus.service    loaded  failed  failed
display-manager.service not-found inactive  dead    display-manager.service
emergency.service   loaded  inactive    dead
getty@tty1.service  loaded  active  running
kmod-static-nodes.service   loaded  active  exited
plymouth-quit-wait.service  not-found inactive  dead    plymouth-quit-wait.service
plymouth-start.service  not-found inactive  dead    plymouth-start.service
rc-local.service    loaded  inactive    dead
rescue.service  loaded  inactive    dead
syslog.service  not-found inactive  dead    syslog.service
systemd-ask-password-console.service    loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-ask-password-wall.service   loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-binfmt.service  loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-fsck-root.service   loaded  active  exited
systemd-hostnamed.service   loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-hwdb-update.service loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-initctl.service loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-journal-catalog-update.service  loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-journal-flush.service   loaded  active  exited
systemd-journald.service    loaded  active  running
systemd-localed.service loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-logind.service  loaded  activating auto-restart restart Login Service   
systemd-machine-id-commit.service   loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-machined.service    loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-modules-load.service    loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-networkd.service    loaded  activating auto-restart restart Network Service 
systemd-random-seed.service loaded  active  exited
systemd-remount-fs.service  loaded  active  exited
systemd-resolved.service    loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-sysctl.service  loaded  active  exited
systemd-sysusers.service    not-found inactive  dead    systemd-sysusers.service
systemd-timedated.service   loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-timesyncd.service   loaded  active  running
systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service  loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service  loaded  active  exited
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service  loaded  active  exited
systemd-udev-trigger.service    loaded  active  exited
systemd-udevd.service   loaded  active  running
systemd-update-done.service loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service    loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-update-utmp.service loaded  active  exited
systemd-user-sessions.service   not-found inactive  dead    systemd-user-sessions.service
systemd-vconsole-setup.service  loaded  active  exited
-.slice loaded  active  active
machine.slice   loaded  inactive    dead
system-getty.slice  loaded  active  active
system.slice    loaded  active  active
user.slice  loaded  active  active
dbus.socket loaded  active  running
syslog.socket   loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-initctl.socket  loaded  active  listening
systemd-journald-audit.socket   loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-journald-dev-log.socket loaded  active  running
systemd-journald.socket loaded  active  running
systemd-networkd.socket loaded  active  listening
systemd-udevd-control.socket    loaded  active  running
systemd-udevd-kernel.socket loaded  active  running
dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dVBOX_HARDDISK_VB661dfc8e\x2d76a9fb53\x2dpart1.swap loaded  active  active
dev-disk-by\x2duuid-adf6eeae\x2d5ab2\x2d42a3\x2d9e1d\x2d0fed7f32a451.swap   loaded  active  active
dev-sdb1.swap   loaded  active  active
basic.target    loaded  active  active
busnames.target loaded  inactive    dead
emergency.target    loaded  inactive    dead
getty.target    loaded  active  active
graphical.target    loaded  inactive    dead
local-fs-pre.target loaded  active  active
local-fs.target loaded  active  active
multi-user.target   loaded  inactive    dead
network-pre.target  loaded  inactive    dead
network.target  loaded  inactive    dead
nss-user-lookup.target  loaded  inactive    dead
paths.target    loaded  active  active
remote-fs-pre.target    loaded  inactive    dead
remote-fs.target    loaded  active  active
rescue.target   loaded  inactive    dead
shutdown.target loaded  inactive    dead
slices.target   loaded  active  active
sockets.target  loaded  active  active
swap.target loaded  active  active
sysinit.target  loaded  active  active
time-sync.target    loaded  active  active
timers.target   loaded  active  active
umount.target   loaded  inactive    dead
systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer    loaded  active  waiting
```

Does anyone have any idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: ---------------

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the DBus tools should be built and installed when DBus support is enabled in the Qt libs; probably the same applies to the XML tools.

When you execute the `configure` command it provides a summary of the applied configuration, but that scrolls out quite quickly before the process exits. To see it you'll have to scroll up the console output, or pipe it into a file; I recommend to leave out the `make` call until you're sure you got the configuration right. There you should be able to see which features are en-/disabled, and perhaps get a clue why not.

For additional `configure` options to force features see

```
./configure --help
```

This should give you a first hint where to start, and what you can try out to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Murphy. I will try your suggestion and post the results.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by @Murphy, I ran ./config and got the following results:

```
Build type:    linux-g++
Architecture:  i386
Platform notes:

            - Also available for Linux: linux-kcc linux-icc linux-cxx

Build .................. libs tools docs translations
Configuration ..........  system-sqlite release largefile stl precompile_header mmx 3dnow sse sse2 sse3 ssse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 avx  minimal-config small-config medium-config large-config full-config qt3support accessibility opengl shared reduce_exports ipv6 clock-gettime clock-monotonic mremap getaddrinfo ipv6ifname getifaddrs inotify system-jpeg system-mng system-png png system-tiff system-freetype system-zlib nis cups iconv glib dbus dbus-linked openssl-linked x11sm xshape xvideo xsync xrender mitshm fontconfig xkb alsa icu concurrent xmlpatterns multimedia audio-backend svg script scripttools declarative release
Debug .................. no
Qt 3 compatibility ..... yes
QtDBus module .......... yes (linked)
QtConcurrent code ...... yes
QtGui module ........... yes
QtScript module ........ yes
QtScriptTools module ... yes
QtXmlPatterns module ... yes
Phonon module .......... no
Multimedia module ...... auto
SVG module ............. yes
WebKit module .......... no
JavaScriptCore JIT ..... To be decided by JavaScriptCore
Declarative module ..... yes
Declarative debugging ...yes
Support for S60 ........ no
Symbian DEF files ...... no
STL support ............ yes
PCH support ............ yes
MMX/3DNOW/SSE/SSE2/SSE3. yes/yes/yes/yes/yes
SSSE3/SSE4.1/SSE4.2..... yes/yes/yes
AVX..................... yes
Graphics System ........ default
IPv6 support ........... yes
IPv6 ifname support .... yes
getaddrinfo support .... yes
getifaddrs support ..... yes
Accessibility .......... yes
NIS support ............ yes
CUPS support ........... yes
Iconv support .......... yes
Glib support ........... yes
GStreamer support ...... no
PulseAudio support ..... no
Large File support ..... yes
GIF support ............ plugin
TIFF support ........... plugin (system)
JPEG support ........... plugin (system)
PNG support ............ yes (system)
MNG support ............ plugin (system)
zlib support ........... system
Session management ..... yes
OpenGL support ......... yes (Desktop OpenGL)
OpenVG support ......... no
NAS sound support ...... no
XShape support ......... yes
XVideo support ......... yes
XSync support .......... yes
Xinerama support ....... runtime
Xcursor support ........ runtime
Xfixes support ......... runtime
Xrandr support ......... runtime
Xrender support ........ yes
Xi support ............. runtime
MIT-SHM support ........ yes
FontConfig support ..... yes
XKB Support ............ yes
immodule support ....... yes
GTK theme support ...... no
SQLite support ......... plugin (system)
OpenSSL support ........ linked (linked)
Alsa support ........... yes
ICD support ............ no
libICU support ......... yes
Use system proxies ..... no
```

I don't know why some modules (like QtDBus) are note building, when they clearly should, and others (like GStreamer) are not even configured to be built, despite having it installed in the system.

Any suggestions will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer. You're supposed to add findings that help to hunt down your problem to the question instead.